# How to 'Find' elements served by Angular components using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to create a Chrome Extension to inject a dialog in a page.
The page appears to be developed using Angular:

```
<body al-exchange al-window-click ng-controller="PageCtrl as PageCtrl" class="" ng-class="...
```

My issue:
I am trying to find a button **(the only button)** on the page, but the selector I am using cannot seem to find it.

```
// jquery
function FindButton(){
   $(function(){
   var num = 0; 

   $(":button").each(function(btn){
     num = num + 1; 
   })
  alert('Jquery - There are ' + num + ' buttons in page');
 }); 
}

var filter = {...

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener( 
  FindButton, filter );
```

The code above works if I just display an alert dialog, so I know it's firing.

I noticed (**using the Chrome dev tools**) I can see the button element if I use the Inspect tool but if I use the 'view page source' tool there are no actual controls, just div's and script tags.

<== **I have edited my original question to include the button html I hope this helps.** :-) ==>

```
<div ng-if="some_method_here()" class="acceloCreateEditPageCardContainer__footer" ng-trasclude="footer">==$0
   <create-edit-page-card-footer class="flex">
    <!-->
    <!-->
        <button ng-disabled="some_text_here" ng-click="some_text_here" 
                class="fillbutton fillbutton--blue" ng-class="some_ngclass_here">Save</button>
   </create-edit-page-card-footer class="flex">
</div>
```

*I have edited this question further*

I have now **updated my code in my extension**. I now use the 'DOMContentLoaded' event to searches for the button.

The alert fires but it still says there are 0 buttons in page.

```
//=======background.js====================
function AddListner(){
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', 
    $(function(){
      var num = 0; 
  
      $(":button").each(function(btn){
        num = num + 1; 
    })
    alert('There are ' + num + ' buttons in page');
    })
  );
}

var filter = { ....

chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener( 
  AddListner,
  filter );
```

Any help in understanding what is happening, would be great! :-)

Comment: Make sure to look for the button _after the app has loaded_ (this would be the case for any client side framework). Beyond that there is nothing special about angular per se; it is a matter of specifying the correct selector. If you continue to have an issue, post the html for the button in question, so we can help regarding the selector.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to include more information

Comment: @Neea, I worked out how to select the button finally, thanks to your input. Create an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was really shooting in the dark, it ended up being extremely simple:

The answer was to use document.querySelector and search for a button element with two classes:

```
document.querySelector("button.fillbutton.fillbutton--blue").addEventListener('click', function () { ... some function here ... }
```

Thanks so much for your response Neea, it gave me the confidence I needed to  keep trying. :-)